# Ways to say "My phone ran out of power"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, formality

What are some other ways to say "My phone ran out of power", meaning my battery got depleted. What is the level of formality of each one?

Comment: Very informal: "My phone is out of juice."
Very formal: "My phone's battery is completely discharged."

Comment: Also, "My battery is running low" / "...is running out" / "...has run out."

Comment: There is something about this question which reminds me of the old joke about a schoolboy and a fountain pen (we used them when I was a lad, and they were all right until they ran out of ink). The joke was - Boy says "Please sir, my pen's run out", Teacher "Then run out and catch it dear boy". I guess modern child says "My battery's run out..."

Comment: My phone **died** (informal).

Comment: Even more formal: "Please be aware that the battery of my mobile telephone [*or* cellular telephone] is completely discharged."

Answer (score 3):

Some other ways (including some provided in the comments):

#### Formal

- My phone's battery is completely discharged - @Canadian_Yankee
- My phone's battery is drained.

#### Informal

- My phone ran out of juice - @Canadian_Yankee
- My phone is out of juice
- My phone ran out of battery
- My phone is out of battery
- My phone died - @TypelA
- My phone went out